# UITextField make part not editable

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

How can I make a part of the UITextField non-editable? What I mean by this is I set a default value to the text field and I only want users to be able to edit the part that they add. Is this possible? If so, please tell me how I can go about doing this.

Comment: give an example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *myString;    

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myString = @"whatever";
    self.myTextField.text = self.myString;
    self.myTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     // Avoid user replacing characters from myString
     if (range.location < [self.myString length])
     {
         return NO;
     }
     // Allow adding or replacing new characters after myString
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo I really appreciate your answer but I placed the @property line in my Header and the rest in my ViewController.m, I am getting 2 about the exact same thing stating "Property 'myTextField' not found on object type of 'ViewController *'" Please help. They are on the last 2 lines of viewDidLoad function. "self.myTextField...." lines

Comment: You should connect a reference outlet from your Storyboard (or XIB) from the UITextField to property called `myTextField` (or a name of your choosing). If you don't have Storyboard nor XIB, then you can create the textField programmatically and store it as a property.

Comment: I do have a storyboard but the outlet is not coming up...please help http://imgur.com/BJJe6dy

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html

Comment: I'm sorry man I'm really confused at what you're getting at..please explain I'm pretty new with Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // get textField.text string using range and compare it to your default.
    // return no if you don't want it to change
}
```

Alternatively instead of using a "default" value, consider using a placeholder value instead, this will be cleared when they type anything and if you leave it blank you could just accept the placeholder value as the default.